# Is it possible to change input z-index on Android 3.2 / 4.0.4?

Tags: android, html, css, android-layout, android-3.2-honeycomb

In Android 3.2, all my Input-fields overlapps everything after tap, when it gets focus. I have a sticky footer at the bottom of the page, which should be over the input field. After an Update to Android 4.0.4 I get the same problems. This is on an Samsung Galaxy Tab 10.1n. I try this page on an other Android Smartphone with Android 4.1.2 without this problem.

Trying to change the z-index of the input-field or the footer does not work. I have styles for input:focus, but it looks like Android has his owne OS-Styles.

Have everyone the same Problems or have everyone an idea how to fix this bug - please without Script?

[Here the link to the testpage](http://wp1033656.wp056.webpack.hosteurope.de/www/test.html)

[Here a Screenshot from the Samsung Galaxy Tab 10.1n with Android 3.2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NjHSN.jpg)